# Golang TCP dial error: host is down

Tags: go, networking, tcp

```
net.Dial("tcp", "192.168.1.100:3000")
```

The above call give me `dial tcp 192.168.1.100:3000: connect: host is down`.

I can successfully ping the endpoint. I wonder what will be the cause of this error. What will be the possible causes of `host is down`?

Let me provide more details. The endpoint I am dialing to is running mysql server. And I can successfully connect to it with command line. The endpoint is host in a NAS.

Further investigation, I believe the error message is from https://github.com/golang/go/blob/60e3ebb9cba900f7b2f559b472726cee47e823c0/src/net/fd_unix.go#L94

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out why. This is because of firewall settings. This situation is caused by using Little Snitch which will check executable has valid code signature or not. If the executable does not have valid code signature, the request is filtered and Little Snitch will return error number 64 which mean host is down in Mac.

Answer (score 2):

The error message means that no TCP connection can not be created to the given IP address at the given port. Your check with ping does not help much since ping does use ICMP to reach the host contrary to your use of TCP. A successful ping just means that the host is reachable in general but not that a TCP connection to the host on the given port will succeed. It might even be that such a connection succeeds but ping fails since it is blocked by a firewall rule.

Typical causes for the problem you see are:

- You've used the wrong target IP and/or port.
- There is no application listening at this port at the target machine at all, i.e. maybe you forgot to start the server or it crashed or it was configured wrongly.
- The application is only listening on localhost and is thus not reachable from outside the machine.
- Firewall rules either at the server machine or between client and server block access.

Comment: Thanks. Let me provide more details. The endpoint I am dialing to is running mysql server. And I can successfully connect to it with command line. The endpoint is host in a NAS.

Comment: @MortyChoi: What is working command line you use to connect to the server? Are you sure that you are using the same port when connecting to it on the command line, since mysql usually uses port  3306 and not 3000. 3000 is instead typically used for some web servers which should only be accessible on the local machine because there is some real web server in front of these which just proxies the requests.

Comment: I am using `mysql -u username -h host -p` to connect to the server. For the port I just customised it to use 3000.

Comment: @MortyChoi: I don't see you specifying a port. Option '-p' sets the password, option '-P' instead sets the port.

Comment: Ya I am using `mysql -u username -h host -P port -p`. Sorry for not double checking before commenting.

Comment: @MortyChoi: if you are using the mysql command and the go program both from the same machine to the same machine and port and one works while the other not then something is really strange. I recommend to make a packet capture (wireshark, tcpdump or similar) for both connections to see the difference.

Comment: Will there be any chance that the golang tcp implementation has bug?

Comment: @MortyChoi: very very unlikely since this code is used heavily. It is more likely that you think that you connect to port 3000 from the same machine with mysql but actually did not.

Comment: Okay I will further investigte.